# Getting text length in pixels for all languages in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, combobox

I wanted to know how we can calculate the length of a text in a checkbox in pixels. The language of the text can be changed to any language, like english, romanian, spanish, chinese, japanese, etc.

I have a checkbox followed by a combobox in the same line, so that when the length of the text of the checkbox changes(when language is changed) , I want to change the location of the combobox accordingly, so that the checkbox text is not truncated by the combobox.

I tried TextRenderer.MeasureText method. It works for chinese and japanese, but for other languages it is not returning the correct value.

Is there a better way to find out the text length in pixels?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `AutoSize`? Of course the exact size can't be inferred but it's nearly/close to the exact size.

Comment: Using [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) (or an appropriate overload) seems to be the prefered way. Do you have an example for a text and font where the expected length does not equal the length you got from that method? (please also tell us the expected and returned length)

Comment: AutoSize does not solve the issue

Comment: @Corak, the MeasureText method has parameters (string , font). So, if my checkbox text language keeps changing, I am not sure what font I should give there.

Comment: Sorry @KingKing, Autosize does solve the issue. Thanks.
I put the checkbox text as autosize and used the size of the checkbox to set the location of the combobox.
Appreciate your quick response. :)

Comment: @DeepakMenonK - the font doesn't change with the language. Or do you switch for example from Arial to Times New Roman, when you change the language?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WPF. 
You can bind actualWidth of your checkbox or a fake, invisible textbox to your ViewModel and put your text there.

When text changes a control width would change which will be reflected in you property changed

It's walkaround a bit but it's simple and will work :)